# Sitecore ECM : Message preview gives wrong output

Tags: ssl, sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I have a Multi Site system, version 6.5 with ECM 1.3. E-mails are sent using SSL/TLS over port 587, all connections are running and tested and I am able to send test-mails.

When creating a new Newsletter in my ECM and then going to the Message Preview, I do not see the (empty) layout of the newsletter, but instead Sitecore displays the home page of the website itsself?! This issue occurs for every template except the HTML Message. When sending the Newsletter as a test mail, I receive an e-mail with more or less the layout of the website, as shown in the preview.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Hessel

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Newsletter Branch (i.e.$name under Branches >> Branch Newsletter) and Email Message Root (i.e. Email Message root under Branches >> Branch Newsletter >> $name) have been assigned the Custom Newsletter Template.

- Check Email Message Root by clicking this on the Ribbon (You might already know this but .....)

  - Select the Email Message Root in the tree.
  - In the Ribbon click Presentation >> Layout >> Details and the Layout Details dialog box should give you the info.
  - Simultaneously also check the content and presentation binding is in place and relevant renderings like **Set Page Title**, **Basic Newsletter Title&Text** and **Basic Newsletter Header** are in place.
- Check in Custom Newsletter branch template the layout details of $name item.

  - Make sure for the default device your Custom Newsletter Layout is set and also these type of controls are set in their respective placeholders.

    - **Process Personalization Tokens** (sublayout) & **Custom NewsLetter TitleAndText** in email-content (placeholder).
    - **Set Page Title** in Html-title(placeholder).

Once these settings are configured correctly, try creating a new item from that branch and hopefully the preview should work.

Let us know how you get along and if the above was of any help.

Comment: Hi Shiroop, thanx for the response. It seems that everything is set according to your remarks. I just found out that when I look ate the MESSAGE PREVIEW, I see the website, but when I open a PREVIEW (Presentations -> Preview) I do see the correct newsletter. However : when I send a test e-mail the system sends "the website" and not the newsletter?!

Comment: Hi Hzzl, did you manage to resolve this or have taken a different approach to this issue? Let me know how did you go about fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this might be a security issue, when we try to preview a message for recipient (! not the context user !) who doesn’t have permission to read the message.

Try to set **CheckReceiverRights** setting value to **true** in **Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config** file. In case, it is security issue, you will be alerted in the preview window.